# How can I comment multiple lines in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We always need to comment multiple code lines during programming. In visual studio code, I want to know how to comment multiple lines?

Comment: Select then Ctrl+K+C

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In windows you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> in mac you can do  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to make multiple comment

```
// public function index()
// {
//     $badgeIcon = BadgeIcon::all();
//     return $this->showAll($badgeIcon);
// }
```

Then if you want to un-comment then select the lines again and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>(in windows) again <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>(in mac).